# Find full path when given "blah\..\..\target\some_file" in VisualStudio debugger

Tags: path, windows-10, visual-studio-2019

Debugging a VisualStudio 2019 project, build errors indicate

> Source file 'C:\Users\blah..\ ..\target\some_file.jar'

(ignore space).

I'd like to make sure the file that is being sought is where it is being sought, but I can't tell where that is for the dots.  How does one identify the actual path being sought?

Answer (score 0):

The dots are used in a build command in VS, and indicate a jump in the file structure of one level for each pair of dots.

Thus, the command "cd C:\Users\blah..\ ..\target" would change the directory to c:\target.